# Date time difference miss to calculate the days to hour

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date time difference-

I need to calculate those days also into hour.

```
$start = '2016-05-26 19:05:00';
$end = '2016-05-29 17:05:00';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format("%h Hours %i Min %s Sec"); //22 Hours 0 Min 0 Sec
```

I know this:

```
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

I try this:

```
echo $interval->format("(%h + %d * 24) Hours %i Min %s Sec"); //(22 + 8 * 24) Hours 0 Min 0 Sec
```

Comment: Get the day difference and multiply it by 24 and add it to the hours.

Comment: I really don;t know how to do that

Comment: `echo ($interval->days * 24 + $interval->h), ' Hours ', $interval->i, ' Min ', $inteval->s, ' Sec';`

Comment: Try to use `strtotime()` it will give you time in secound and then you can easily get it into hours.

Comment: @Mark, it's perfect

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker, `$interval->days` not working perfectly on my server, I change this to `$interval->d` and now its working. I debug the whole interval object.

Comment: `$interval->d` will cause problems with longer timespans, because it is the difference in days within a month; whereas `$interval->days` will span months and years

Comment: At my case if i use the days then it always show me `6015 days`, and that time i use the `d` and get the desire result. But thanks for your informative share.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2007-09-01 04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2012-09-11 10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';                        
echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';
echo (($since_start->days)*24)+$since_start->h.' Total Hours<br>';
```

Use this claculate the days and then multiple by 24 plus remaining hours

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, all though it cannot be done automatically for you, you have to write code.

Here is all you need:

```
$start = '2016-05-26 19:05:00';
$end = '2016-05-29 17:05:00';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

// Below this line is where the magic takes place:

$hourDiff = ($interval->d*24)+($interval->h); //here we calculate the hours

echo $hourDiff //prints 77 because 2 days*24 hours each + 22 hours = 77
```

In my example I also take into account the years and months (y and m respectively) but you can delete those if you don't want them.

Comment: not required longer calculation. take it simple : `$interval->days * 24 + $interval->h`. it's give same result

Comment: Given that different months have different numbers of days, and even years have different numbers of days, using `$interval->days` is more accurate than assuming that every month has 30 days, and that every year has 365 days

Comment: Thanks for have some time.

Comment: Modified my answer to only utilise the days and hours, as the question suggested.